# Postgresql bug, can't find the row with exact same string

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

Just a little conundrum I have faced with.

I have a table `player` with `login` column(varchar(255)).
The rows are inserted by Java code.

I've a record with id = 173 login = PLN2test:
When I search for this record by the following query,

`SELECT login FROM player WHERE login = 'PLN2test'`

or even:
`SELECT login FROM player WHERE login = (SELECT login FROM player WHERE id = 173)`

I get zero results!

However when I try:
`SELECT login FROM player WHERE login LIKE '%PLN2test'`

or
`SELECT login FROM player WHERE login LIKE 'PLN2test%'`

I get my record.

Please can you tell me why this is happening?
Is there known bug on the postgres side?
How I can debug query execution and understand why it returns unexpected result?

P.S. `SELECT length(login) FROM player WHERE id = 173` gives me 8

```
show lc_collate;
 lc_collate 
------------
 en_US.utf8
(1 row)
```

```
show client_encoding ;
 client_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)
```

OS version: Ubuntu 20.04

It looks like colleague of mine just recently changed a collate type from `C.UTF-8` to `en_US.utf8)`. Can this lead to such a behavior? And how to migrate data to new type now?

Comment: A) If there is an index on the field try reindexing B) It is an encoding issue. What does `show lc_collate ;` and `show client_encoding ;`  in `psql` return?  What encoding is the Java code using? Add answers as update to your question. Also what OS and version and have there been any OS updates lately? Again add to your question.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver There is no index on this field. I've updated my question.

Comment: The update does not include the Java encoding or the OS information.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver looks like colleague of mine just recently changed a collate type(from C.UTF-8 to en_US.utf8), can this lead to such a behavior?  And how to migrate data to new type now?

Comment: Changed where, the database(which should not be possible), on the column or in Java?  Also the OS information is needed. This is a question where more information is better.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response Adrian,
this was changed for the whole database by: update pg_database set datcollate='en_US.utf8', datctype='en_US.utf8'; 
I will update my question with OS version shortly

Comment: What you have found is that you should not go around changing  system catalogs(pg_database) manually. Per [Locale](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/locale.html): "Some locale categories must have their values fixed when the database is created. You can use different settings for different databases, but once a database is created, you cannot change them for that database anymore. LC_COLLATE and LC_CTYPE are these categories."

Comment: Recommend that either @AdrianKlaver (prefferably) or OlegBaranenko submit the above comments as an answer. It seems likely that someone else may encounter this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have found is that you should not go around changing system catalogs(pg_database) manually. Per [Locale](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/locale.html): "Some locale categories must have their values fixed when the database is created. You can use different settings for different databases, but once a database is created, you cannot change them for that database anymore. LC_COLLATE and LC_CTYPE are these categories."